# How do I change "root" to another partition for Debian 11 Live LXDE image for bootable USB?

Tags: debian, live-usb

I want to create a bootable Debian Live OS with overlay partition (i.e. save changes on it). But I want to create multiple partitions, not one. I want to install syslinux to one partition, Debian OS-live Image files to another partition, and finally overlay partition to other one. To achieve this, I read official Debian pages for help [description of preparing USB for boot of Debian OS](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch04s03.html.en) and syslinux documents.
I used syslinux commands and I managed to get boot menu and I could load *vmlinuz-5.10.0-8-amd64* image since I copied it into the same folder with syslinux in sdb1(boot partition, i.e. **/mnt/sdb1/syslinux/vmlinuz-5.10.0-8-amd64**). But I could not load initrd.img file which is located in sdb2(second partition i.e. **/mnt/sdb2/live/initrd.img-5.10.0-8-amd64**) with this command in menu.cfg in syslinux folder in sdb1. What I did is here in **menu.cfg** file which is under **/dev/sdb1/syslinux/** folder  :

```
  INCLUDE stdmenu.cfg
  MENU title Main Menu
  DEFAULT Debian GNU/Linux 64 bit
  LABEL Debian GNU/Linux 64 bit
     SAY "Booting Debian GNU/Linux Live (kernel 5.10.0-8-amd64)..."
     LINUX vmlinuz-5.10.0-8-amd64
     APPEND root=/dev/sdb2 fromhd=/dev/sdb initrd=/dev/sdb2/live/initrd.img-5.10.0-8-amd64 boot=live swap=true persistence persistence-storage=filesystem persistence-media=removable-usb union=overlay components locales=tr_TR.UTF-8 splash
```

Result is :

[image]

The command **root=/dev/sdb2** and **initrd=/dev/sdb2/live/initrd.img-5.10.0-8-amd64** does not work, it gives  ** No such file or directory ** error. Please help, why didn't it work? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `APPEND`, you are just adding parameters to the kernel command line. But with modern kernels, it would be the bootloader's job to load the `initrd.img` file, not the kernel's. Both GRUB and SYSLINUX use the `initrd` command for this purpose.

For historical reasons, Syslinux understands the `initrd=` option on the `APPEND` line and handles it specially. All the other options on the `APPEND` line are just handed over to the kernel (and initrd scripts) for processing.

But Syslinux has no clue on how Linux will be naming the various devices when it boots up, and it seems to me Syslinux has no way (no documented way, at least) to refer to any other device than the one it's currently booting from.

The `Loading vmlinuz-5.10.0-8-amd64... ok` message is printed by Syslinux, just like the next line. Having the initrd file in a different partition than the kernel file means Syslinux won't be able to access the initrd file at all. **Syslinux needs its configuration, the kernel, and the initrd file to all be in the same partition.**

A modern version of GRUB would be flexible enough to do what you want, but such a custom installation of GRUB will take some doing.